# Roslyn slower than CodeDom

Tags: vb.net, roslyn, codedom, runtime-compilation

I am using Roslyn to generate a runtime dll using a number of VB files on disk.
I am first creating syntax trees from all those files and then using them for creating VBCompilation and them emitting the assembly. The whole process takes ~ 10 min. Creating syntax trees takes up a significant portion of that time.
If I compile the files using CodeDom, it takes ~3 min.
Is there a way to make Roslyn compile files faster?

Comment: If the CodeDom is faster for your purposes, then why don't you just use it?

Comment: Because it does not contain latest language features and is being deprecated

Comment: A large part of that is probably loading Roslyn DLLs.  Compiling a second time is likely to be much faster.